# janus vim-plugin autocompiling scala

Tags: scala, vim

I noticed that when I save .scala files with the janus plugin for vim installed, that this attempts to compile the file and located any compilation errors.

Does anyone know how to disable this?

Comment: Janus is a distribution of plugins; I think the _Syntastic_ plugin is responsible for this behavior. Read up on the documentation; many people advise against these distributions, because there's "too much magic" involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [Syntastic's documentation](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/blob/master/doc/syntastic.txt), turning off the automatic checking globally is:

```
let g:syntastic_mode_map = { 'mode': 'passive',
                           \ 'active_filetypes': [],
                           \ 'passive_filetypes': [] }
```

and just for Scala it would be:

```
let g:syntastic_mode_map = { 'mode': 'active',
                           \ 'active_filetypes': [],
                           \ 'passive_filetypes': ['scala'] }
```

Comment: You are correct that it was syntastic that was doing this.  Adding the line "call janus#disable_plugin('syntastic')" to vimrc.before also globally disables the syntax checking.

Comment: Okay. Please be aware that when you deviate too much from the default set of plugins, the use of a Vim distribution like _Janus_ doesn't make much sense. Many people recommend to pick each plugin explicitly, and avoid the complexities of distributions.